# Generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: c++

Can someone point me to a valid library that implements an efficient and reliable computation of the generalized hypergeometric functions in C/C++? In particular I'm looking for the 3F2({a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2},z) hypergeometric function that is not available for gnu scientific library gsl.

Python has the library mpmath that is very very good, I would like to find something similar to the hyp3f2 done for c/C++.

Comment: Haven't used it but it might be exactly what you need http://www.boost.org - Boost C++ Libraries

Comment: No it seems boost hasn't the generalized hypergeometric function, but only the hypergeometric distribution that is another thing.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214323/